# Clojure Spec parsing issue

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm working through some programming language exercise and I'm trying to use Spec to define the language syntax and parse it. The code is simple as below. But I'm having problem with how to do parsing correctly with sub-expression.

```
(:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
        [clojure.edn :as e])

(s/def ::const-exp integer?)
(s/def ::var-exp symbol?)

;; -(1,2)
(s/def ::diff-exp (s/cat :minus #{'-} :exps (s/coll-of ::expr :count 2)))

;; zero? 2
(s/def ::zero?-exp (s/cat :zero? #{'zero?} :exp1 ::expr))

;; if x then y else c
(s/def ::if-exp (s/cat :if #{'if} :exp1 ::expr :then #{'then} :exp2 ::expr :else #{'else} :exp3 ::expr))

;; let x = y in c
(s/def ::let-exp (s/cat :let #{'let} :id ::var-exp :eq #{'=} :exp1 ::expr :in #{'in} :body ::expr))

(s/def ::expr
  (s/or
   :const-exp ::const-exp
   :diff-exp ::diff-exp
   :var-exp ::var-exp
   :zero?-exp ::zero?-exp
   :if-exp ::if-exp
   :let-exp ::let-exp))

(defn pgm [x] (e/read-string (format "[%s]" x)))
```

So far it can parse basic expressions fine.
like `(s/conform ::expr (pgm "let x = 7 in x"))`

But for the example of the let expression, if I change the last x to some complex expression, `(s/conform ::expr (pgm "let x = 7 in let y = 8 in y"))`, the parsing would fail with the following explain:

`In: [6] val: (y = 8 in y) fails spec: :eopl.let-spec/let-exp at: [:let-exp] predicate: (cat :let #{(quote let)} :id :eopl.let-spec/var-exp :eq #{(quote =)} :exp1 :eopl.let-spec/expr :in #{(quote in)} :body :eopl.let-spec/expr),  Extra input`

It seems like it cannot look-ahead or do recursive conform properly? Or am I defining the syntax wrong here?

How shall I solve this to let it parse correctly with Spec?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll have a much easier time using a proper parser, maybe like [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse). It's possible to use clojure.spec for [some parsing](http://taylorwood.github.io/2017/10/04/clojure-spec-boolean.html) but I'm not sure how tractable it'd be for this case.

Comment: I also doubt that spec is suited for parsing full-fledged language syntaxes, though for this particular problem you could try using `s/alt` instead of `s/or`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed from s/or to s/alt in this case, and it indeed works